# Appium clicking dynamic list item

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I am trying to automate clicking the item of the dynamic scrollable list item containing specific text. The text of list item is getting using api call, it may/will be changed based on api response.

For example suppose i have 3 list item say apple, mango and banana. If i want to click on item that contain the text banana, how can i do that?

My Appium Desktop inspector my xml file for the dynamic list looks like following

> ```
> <android.view.ViewGroup content-desc="Dashboard_lv_Container">
>  <android.view.ViewGroup>
>   <android.widget.ListView content-desc="Dashboard_lv">
>    <android.widget.LinearLayout>
>     <android.view.ViewGroup>
>      <android.widget.FrameLayout content-desc="item_1">
>       <android.view.ViewGroup>
>        <android.view.ViewGroup>
>           <android.widget.TextView>
>        <android.view.ViewGroup>
>           <android.widget.ImageView>
>    <android.widget.LinearLayout>
>     <android.view.ViewGroup>
>      <android.widget.FrameLayout content-desc="item_2">
>       <android.view.ViewGroup>
>        <android.view.ViewGroup>
>          <android.widget.TextView>
>        <android.view.ViewGroup>
>          <android.widget.ImageView>
> ```

I want to select the item with certain text contain in **android.widget.TextView**. How can i do that?

Comment: Your code attempts? Error stack trace?

Comment: i solve it for android using **UiSelector.text('banana')".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it using the **UiSelector**

```
try {
     MobileElement element=driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"banana\")"));
    element.click();
}catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
    System.out.println("Element not found");
}
```

For the scrollable list i did it using **UiScrollable**
description

```
try {
     MobileElement element=driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(\"new UiSelector().description(\"Dashboard_lv\")\").getChildByText(\"new UiSelector().text(\"banana\")\")"));
    element.click();
}catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
    System.out.println("Element not found");
}
```